# Android intent doesn't work on .apk files

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing a File Manager, and I open files this way:

```
fileName = fileToOpen.getName();
fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileToOpen);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileName));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

This can handle almost all extension, but when I click on .apk files an ActivityNotFoundException gets thrown. I would like to launch the android installation screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only on Android 7.0+ will the package installer know how to work with `content` `Uri` values. For earlier versions of Android, you have no choice but to have the APK on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) somewhere and use a `file` `Uri`.